# Exclude some folders from RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not good with Apache mod_rewrite and I have to rewrite all requests passing them as a GET parameter to a PHP page (eg. `index.php?_REQUEST=$`) which will check them and redirect to the right location according to a setting written in an INI file.

The rewriting must exclude some directories (in which the access is direct):

- `admin/`
- `api/`
- `bin/cmd/` (but NOT `bin`)

How can I do this in the .htaccess?

Is it possible to pass the request to an environment variable (`$_ENV`) instead of the GET variable?

Comment: "It's possible..." - is that a question or a statement? Which would you prefer? Have you tried _anything_ so far? You don't actually _need_ to pass the request at all. Assuming you internally rewrite to `index.php` then the request is available to PHP in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: @w3d I've tried with this:
`RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_REQUEST=$1 [L]`
But doesn't work, it pass all the request but no filter is applied to the directory (I tried only with one just for try). Anyway sorry for my bad english, I meant if you can pass the request in a env var but yes I can use REQUEST_URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your .htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule !^(admin|api|bin/cmd)/ /index.php [L]
```

This *internally rewrites* to `/index.php` when the request does not start with `/admin/`, `/api/`, etc. and is not already `/index.php` (to prevent a rewrite loop). Then access the request via the PHP variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin

The problem with this line (from your comment) is that `%{REQUEST_URI}` always starts with a slash, so this will *never* match, so the following `RewriteRule` *always* rewrites the request.

Comment: I've tried this now but it doesn't work, at first I got an internal server error, so I changed the code: `RewriteRule !^(admin|api|bin/cmd)/ index.php [L]` but it rewrite all to the index.php without filter the directories

Comment: Added `RewriteCond` to prevent a rewrite loop!

Comment: If you get a 500 error then check your server's error log. You need the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` substitution. ie. `/index.php [L]` - unless you already have a `RewriteBase` directive?

Comment: Now I've substitute the old code with your new edit and it works fine, the filter is applied and in the other cases the request is passed to the index.php. Thanks very much for help!